# how to create a dynamic login page using sqlite in phonegap application

Tags: sqlite, cordova

i am working on a PhoneGap app in which i have a login page which authenticates the user...i am trying to set a 4 digit numeric password which will be stored in database when user register itself.then user is required to present the registered password in login feild...if login password matched to the passwored stored in data base then the user will; be directed to the app.

Answer (score 1):

**These are the steps you can follow for making registration and login page :**

1) Open the DB ondeviceready 
Example : 
this.db = window.openDatabase("yourApp", 1, "Your App", 1000000);
    this.db.transaction(this.initDB, this.dbErrorHandler, callback);

2) In callback you can create table. Here you can use "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS" query. Note : please refer Google for full query. Using this your code will create table if it does not exist means first time user has opens your app.

3) Now check is there any entry in this table. for this you can use following snippet : 
"select * from TABLENAME".

4) If result is empty then display Registration page else display Login page.

**Now for Page designing :**

You can use [Jquery Mobile](http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.0/). This is good.

And for DB you can use Sqllite.